# Facebook login on Android pops up web dialog twice during login

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm trying to get Facebook login to work in my Android app.  It does fine when I have the Facebook app installed on the device, but when I don't it pops up a web dialog to prompt me to sign in, and then after I've granted permissions to the app, it takes me back AGAIN to the beginning page to get me to login.  If I just close the dialog at this point, everything works fine and the login in detected.  But if I don't, I get a message saying I've already granted permissions to this app, etc.  I am not asking for read privileges first, and then write privileges later, as some other questions on stack overflow mention.

My code is below, using the latest API release:

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.authButton);
authButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        openFacebookSession();
    }
});

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void openFacebookSession()
{
    // Open a Facebook session to get the user's name
    Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
        {
            if (session.isOpened())
            {
                Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback()
                {
                    // Response Callback
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
                    {
                        if (user != null)
                        {
                            Log.d("in facebook","first name:" + user.getFirstName());
                            Log.d("in facebook","last name:" + user.getLastName());
                            Log.d("in facebook","id:" + user.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }
    });
}
```